# Bootstrap Collapse is collapsing but immediately closing the Collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

When I click on the toggle button the collapse comes down but when ending the down animation the collapse goes up without any interaction.

I tried everything of library references and its order positioning but even then I get the same result as before.

This is my HTML-Code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sti-navbar-light mb-xl-5 justify-content-center" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container align-content-center justify-content-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="./link.php">NAME</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle"
                aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="./link.php" class="nav-link">LINK</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My imports in at the end of the page(tried it also at the header):

```
<script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.7/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="./libs/bootstrap-4.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="./js/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

I also tried the links of the bootstrap documentation but none of them worked.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

So what could be a problem? - cause the order and the links normally should work

Comment: Try using the full version of jQuery, not the slim branch, as that has lots of animation methods removed from it.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of external libraries such as `BootStrap` and `jQuery` requires a certain order so that they can work properly around each other. If you add your libraries randomly and your HTML objects cannot find these, you will probably see weird design issues or javascript codes not working how they supposed to work.

Notice how below snippet adds the external libraries and how the toggle menu successfully works.

I also recommend using full `jQuery` instead of the slim version.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

  
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sti-navbar-light mb-xl-5 justify-content-center" id="mainNav">
    <div class="container align-content-center justify-content-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="./link.php">NAME</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle"
                aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a href="./link.php" class="nav-link">LINK</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even when I use your code I have the same issue .. I see that the codesnippet works like it should but on my page is everytime the same exact problem as before and I have checked that no JS is included after your example of libary includes.

Comment: another interesting fact is that on another page where I am using this it works fine since I changed JQuery above the BootstrapJS but on this site it doesn´t effect anything.

Comment: @subIT Maybe you are using custom CSS style or JS code in your project that interferes with the basic code I shared above. Try opening a new project or page and implement your components one by one. Do not add any custom code until you make sure it works. I only used global external libraries and there is no custom style css or javascript code that would affect how a simple (hamburger) menu works.